# Do I have to include "update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx" in manifest.json of my Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have read the [manifest.json document](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest) but can't find an official directive.

Do I have to add

`"update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx"`

in the `manifest.json` file?

I am just developing an ordinary Chrome Extension and would like to distribute it via Chrome Web Store.

Comment: No, there's no need to add it. The web store adds it in the installed extension automatically.

Comment: Would there be any trouble if I added and submitted for review? Can’t withdraw now.

Comment: Theoretically the web store should simply overwrite this value automatically.

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not need that line on your code at all.
Theoretically, the web store should simply overwrite this value automatically.